# Making in app purchases on android device

Tags: android, firebase, in-app-purchase

In my project, I am using firebase to register and authenticate users and sign into the app. Additionally, I want the user to be able to make purchases for different services using a credit card, but how would I be able to tell which firebase user made the purchase and for which services that was paid for?

Comment: look into paypal for android documentation, but warning, for this you'll need a server. For such a thing you totally need a payment processor. In-app-purchase is not an easy thing as you get confidential information and you try to change people's bank accounts

Comment: Instead of your own server, you could also use Cloud Functions for Firebase. In fact, there is a [sample of integrating Stripe payments](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/stripe).